# Отличие row от column

Tags: html

Верстаю таблицу div-ами, возник вопрос, в чем морфологическое отличие column от row?

Comment: row - строка, column - колонка(столбец), колонка находится в строке.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что вопрос больше касается `bootstrap`, ведь в `html` нет тегов `row` и `column` :)
 Так вот, в бутстрапе стили для класса `row` подогнаны специально таким образом, чтобы содержать блоки с классом `col-*`.
 Объясняю:
`row` имеет `margin-left` и `margin-right` по `-15px`, тогда как `col-*` имеет `padding-left` и `padding-right` по `15px`. Сделано это для того, чтобы крайние колонки в строке "вытягивались", и строка не имела отступы по краям. Если вопрос не касательно `bootstrap` - прошу вас уточнить, что в вашем случае `row`, а что `column`

Answer (score 0):

row - строка, column - колонка(столбец)